# How can I make a GridView with grouped content flow horizontal instead of vertical?

Tags: database, gridview

I have a GridView containing grouped data. The data is always showed vertical by default. I want it to scroll horizontal. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ItemsPanelTemplate` is the one that determines the layout of items. Usually an `ItemsWrapGrid` is used for a `GridView`. That control has a property called `MaximumRowsOrColumns`. Set that to the number of rows you want as a max on a page. The data is then always in a horizontal layout.

For example:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedPersons}}" Margin="0,120,0,0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="20" Width="300" Height="100" Background="AliceBlue">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="60" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" FontSize="42" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="LightGray" Margin="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Black" Margin="30" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </GridView.GroupStyle>
</GridView>
```